# Why does no current flow when I touch a capacitor plate?

Tags: electrostatics

suppose I have two conducting plates with charge +Q and -Q separated by a dielectric. Suppose I am grounded and touch the lower plate. The potential of the lower plate should then be at ground (0V). Why does the charge -Q of lower capacitor plate not flow away into ground? And should there not flow a bit of current to equalize the potentials of ground and the lower plate? Instead the capacitor keeps its charge?

This is confusing me because usually when there is a charged conductor the charge will flow into ground when connected.

Comment: Un-shorted high voltage capacitors can be very very dangerous. Why do you think current won't flow in general?